# Prove the following vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

So I have these three vectors: [i, 2+i, 3]; [2, -i, 4-i}; [3, -1, 2] and I need to show they are linearly independent.  This means that given scalars $x_1, x_2, x_3$ their scalar sum should equal 0.  How would deal with complex numbers in this case?  Would one still perform normal Gaussian elimination or is there some quicker way?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and linear combination of the above vectors

$c_1i+2c_2+3c_3=0$

$2c_1+ic_1-ic-2-c_3=0$

$3c_1+4c_2-ic_2+2c_3=0$

Equating like terms we get

$c_1=0,2c_2+3c_3=0$  ;$2c_1-c_3=0,c_1-c_2=0$

from there we get $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$